# Android ContactId may change?

Tags: android, database, contacts

I wrote an application working with contacts and store some data in db using contactId as key. Being far from computer (terrible english?) I noticed that data tied on a contact is gone. Can it possible that contactId for contact is changed by Android (or any application?). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `CONTACT_ID` is not durable and may change. `LOOKUP_KEY` is supposed to help with this, but I have not played with it yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will play with it. Hope this will help.